# Apache Kafka and Saga

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit, saga

I am considering different message-oriented middleware which I may use on our information system. I've been reading lots of papers and framework documentation. I see that Kafka is not the first choice when we want to do SAGA.

As an example, I read MassTransit's [riders documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/riders/), and it says that "many of concepts and idioms" that are used on classical transports (e.g. ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, etc.) do not apply on Kafka.

What is not possible with Kafka that is usually possible with other MQs (e.g. ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, etc.)?

What, from a transactional point of view, makes it more complicated to use Kafka in a Saga implementation?

Comment: Kafka is a completely different best from traditional message brokers. Asking "what is not possible" is too vague. Please narrow down your question (e.g. "Can Kafka do X that I can do in ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ?").

Comment: Overall, I think you're looking for _[the others] all remove messages from the queue as they are consumed_. Kafka does not

Comment: @JustinBertram, you are right, and that's what i am tring to understand: i mean, i know the differnces regarding message storage, partition management.
I suppose that the critical difference regarding SAGA framework implementation is about transaction management, but available docs are quite vague on this point.

Comment: If you want to know about transaction management in Kafka then you should ask specifically about it. The question should be focused and clear.

Comment: @JustinBertram, ok i will amend my question

Comment: All you did was add another question. Unfortunately that doesn't focus or clarify things at all. If anything, it makes your overall goal less clear.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, do the fact that Kafka keeps consumed messages and other do not present a problem in a Saga implementation. In which point of view may it have an impact on processes orchestration?

Comment: I don't know anything about Saga implementation, but I can imagine its more difficult to track "progress" or guarantee "execution" if you still have some linger state left behind

Comment: Kafka (nor kafka streams) has the concept of a saga as it's usually presented in DDD/CQRS. Kafka is just a plain distributed event log. Everything else you might want has to be built on top of it.